# Xamarin.Android: Delete SMS after sending

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I want to send a SMS and delete the message afterwards (within an hour or two, to be able to check the delivery state).
This is the code I use for sending SMS:

```
SmsManager.Default.SendTextMessage(contact.Text, null,
message.Text, null, null);
```

How can I delete the message? I found a code for deleting SMS as below :

```
ContentResolver.Delete(Android.Net.Uri.Parse("content://sms/" + pid), null, null);
```

but I don't know how to get **pid** of sent message.

Comment: Since KitKat (Android 4.4), only the app chosen as the user's default messaging app has standard write access to the SMS Provider. Attempts by other apps to delete messages will usually just fail silently.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    void deletSms(string message, string number)
    {
        Uri uriSms = Uri.Parse("content://sms/sent");
        Android.Database.ICursor c = ContentResolver.Query(uriSms, new string[] {"_id", "thread_id","address",
            "person", "date", "body" }, null, null, null);
        if (c != null)
        {
            do
            {
                long id = c.GetLong(0);
                long threadId = c.GetLong(1);
                string address = c.GetString(2);
                string body = c.GetString(5);

                if (message.Equals(body) && address.Equals(number))
                {
                    Log.Info(tag, "Deleting SMS with id: " + threadId);
                    ContentResolver.Delete(
                    Uri.Parse("content://sms/" + id), null, null);
                }
            } while (c.MoveToNext());
        }
    }
```

Comment: I get the following error with your code : 
Android.Database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index -1 requested, with a size of 93

Comment: I found out that I need to run c.MoveToNext() once before do{... that is done and now I can find the message, but it does not get deleted yet. The code runs and reaches the ContentResolver.Delete(... line but the SMS is not deleted, what's wrong?